# Angularjs and bindonce - Is this a proper way of using bindonce and how to check that it is working correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here is my question:

I have the following:

```
<li bindonce ng-repeat="value in Types" ng-include="'views/repeaters/types.html'"></li>
```

and I was wondering if this is the correct way to use the bindonce so that ng-repeat will not have a $watch? Should I also put it before the ng-include as well as so:

```
<li bindonce ng-repeat="value in Types" bindonce ng-include="'views/repeaters/types.html'"></li>
```

This way, the ng-include will not have a $watch created for it.

**How about using bindonce for ng-class, ng-click - is it possible to do bo-click, and bo-class ?** Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so this would work (as of now) Check this out : https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `bo-click`, I don't think it's possible, yet. But you can use `bo-class` if you need it. You can have a look at the full list of available directives within `bindonce` [here](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce#attribute-usage).

Also, `bindonce` is the main directive. That means you just have to use it once and inside the wrapper/root element, you use the `bo-*` directives according to your needs.

Finally, there is no way currently to remove the watcher on `ng-repeat`. And if `bindonce` was in fact able to it, you would have to use something called `bo-repeat` or so. It's actually the same for all the directive brought by `bindonce`. You generally have to replace you `ng-*` directives with `bo-*` equivalent directives.